# How to match all saved fingerprints on database saved in bytes c#

Tags: c#, mysql, fingerprint

I can match fingerprints by using sql query "where id". But i want is to identify all fingerprints on the database.

I use zk4500 fingerprint scanner. Mysql c#. sorry for my english and explanation im just a newbie..

```
if (bIdentify)
{

    if (userid.Text == string.Empty)
    {
        return;
    }
    // int ret = zkfp.ZKFP_ERR_OK;

    int fid = 0, score = 0;
    mysqlConn.Open();
    MySqlCommand cmd1 = mysqlConn.CreateCommand();
    cmd1.CommandText = (@"select * from emp_fingerprint where emp_id=?emp_id");
    //cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("?fingerprint_1", dbfp);
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("?emp_id", userid.Text);
    MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd1);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    dr = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
    while (dr.Read())
    {

        byte[] dbfp = new byte[2048];

        dbfp = (byte[])(dr["fingerprint_1"]);
        string a = dr["emp_id"].ToString();
        dr.Close();
        mysqlConn.Close();

        int match = zkfp2.DBMatch(mDBHandle, CapTmp, dbfp);

        if (match > 0)
        {

            textBox1.Text = "Identify success, percent= " + match + "%";

            break;
        }
        else
        {
            textBox1.Text = "Identify fail, percent= " + match + "%";
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

My main problem is i dont know how to store the bytes returned from the finger print scanner in the database and then query those bytes to get the user they belong too

Comment: Firstly format your code. This is the 3rd time you (or someone( has asked this question i have seen and it gets little response for a very good reason... There is no information to go by, it is a device few people have used and it requires searching a 3rd party site for the information. You really need to better articulate your problem. What is the data you are getting? What format is it in? How are you storing it?

Comment: If you CAN supply this information in a timely fashion, ill happily remove my close flag

Comment: i save it on byte format but only i can match fingerprint by using their id on database but  i want to identify the id by using fingerprint

Comment: How many bytes are we talking about ?

Comment: 2048 bytes per fingerprint.sir i want to know how to identify them not using where "id" clause. I try where fingerprint to but no rows return

Comment: If someone scans their finger print twice , is it likely to produce the same bytes? i'm guessing it should

Comment: i think sir they produce same bytes if the fingerprint is well placed. Sir can u help me out on this cause only one fingerprint i matched everytime. i want to display "Id" depends on what fingerprint identify on system and the database.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Mysql and the pl is c#.net

Comment: I have updated the question and added some more detail so at least people can understand what you are trying to achieve. i have also added an answer which gives you the basic idea you need to follow. hoepfully this will help other people understand your problem, and give you a better code answer

Answer (score 1):

**Firstly**

I think your database structure should probably contain a `FingerPrint` table with a foreign key to your users table. This would allow you to store multiple finger prints and alignments for one users.

**Secondly**

I don't think you can query a table via binary data, unless its stored as string.

so (and I am not sure how secure this is), you could probably hash your finger print and store the hash in the database with the finger print bytes in the FingerPrint Table as well as the User PrimaryKey

```
using(SHA1CryptoServiceProvider sha1 = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider())
{
    hash = Convert.ToBase64String(sha1.ComputeHash(byteArray));
}
```

When you want to look up a finger Print you can easily hash the the Finger print data, query your FingerPrint Table for the hash and return the results. You could also double check the finger print bytes you have with the results that are returned (in memory) just to be sure.

The result of all this will give you the Primary key to the User table.

Once you have the users primary key, you can then query your user for the UserId (primary key)

**Update**

Assuming you have a FingerPrint Table

```
Id     // Primary Key
UserId // Foreign key
Hash
FingerPrintData
```

Method To get the hash

```
public string GetHashFromFingerPrintData(byte[] fingerPrintData)
{
    using (SHA1CryptoServiceProvider sha1 = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider())
    {
        return Convert.ToBase64String(sha1.ComputeHash(fingerPrintData));
    }
}
```

Method to compare Finger Print bytes

```
public bool DoFingerPrintsMatch(byte[] a1, byte[] b1)
{
    var i = 0;
    if (a1.Length != b1.Length)
    {
        return i == a1.Length;
    }

    while ((i < a1.Length) && (a1[i] == b1[i]))
    {
        i++;
    }

    return i == a1.Length;
}
```

Method to Get the user Id

```
public int GetUserId(byte[] fingerPrintData)
{
    var connStr = "...";
    var conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);
    var userId = -1;
    try
    {
        conn.Open();

        var sql = "SELECT UserId, FingerPrintData FROM FingerPrint WHERE Continent = @FingerPrintHash";
        var command = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FingerPrintHash", fingerPrintData);
        var reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            byte[] data = reader["FingerPrintData"];
            userId  = reader["UserId"];

            if (DoFingerPrintsMatch(fingerPrintData, data))
            {
                break;
            }

        }

        reader.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }


    return userId;
}
```

***Disclaimer*** : this is fully untested, but surely this should be able to point you in the right direction without having to write the program for you

Comment: Sir, if i save a byte converted to hash string. can be possible to use sql clause to identify?

Comment: @SeanLibiran yes, if you have a finger prints table you can query that table for you user id via the Hash value

Comment: Sir, for example "select id from table where fingerprint_hash=hashvalue"?is this a correct example?

Comment: Sir i try the code that you give and i can save but i try to save different user but same fingerprint and the hash value is different

Comment: @SeanLibiran hang on ill give you a more complete solution